# How to render all ansible variables to yml file with ansible 2.3

Tags: ansible

I am storing all ansible variables to a yaml file (filtering out those that starting with 'ansible_') with this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      all_vars: "{{all_vars | default({}) |combine({item.key: item.value})}}"
    when: "{{not item.key.startswith('ansible_')}}"
    with_dict: "{{vars}}"
  - copy:
      content: "{{ all_vars }}"
      dest: "/tmp/tmp.yml"
```

This is `group_vars/all/defaults.yml`

```
SOME_FACT1: "some-fact"
SOME_FACT2: "{{ SOME_FACT1 }}"
SOME_FACT3: "{{ SOME_FACT2 }}"
```

This works perfectly with ansible 2.2. But with ansible 2.3 (2.3.1.0) the variables are not rendered.
I get results like this:

```
... "SOME_FACT1": "some-fact", "SOME_FACT3": "{{ SOME_FACT2 }}", "SOME_FACT2": "{{ SOME_FACT1 }}" ...
```

How can i force ansible 2.3 to render the variables?

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity

Comment: `vars` is internal object and is templated(better to say _not_ templated) in a special way. Why do you need to do this task?

Comment: I want to execute a python script, that has access to all ansible variables (to create a cloudformation file with troposphere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems, that ansible will not render vars and (I do not know why) all_vars. But any variable inside vars/all_vars is rendered properly when used directly.

So this works:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
          all_vars: "{{all_vars | default([]) |union([item.key + ':{{' + item.key + '|to_json}}'])}}"
    when: "{{not item.key.startswith('ansible_')}}"
    with_dict: "{{vars}}"
  - copy:
      content: "{{ all_vars | join('\n') }}"
      dest: "/tmp/tmp1.yml"
  - template:
      src: "/tmp/tmp1.yml"
      dest: "/tmp/tmp.yml"
```

The idea is:

1. Create a file that lists all variables in the format

   SOME_VAR: {{ SOME_VAR | to_json }}
   ...
2. Render that file using template.

Not very nice, but it works.

Comment: I found this didn't quite work for me in Ansible 2.7, but it provided an idea of how to solve this.  Thanks for asking and answering this, my use case is very similar.